# Two problems relating principal curvatures and circles contained in surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

> 1. Let  $k_1=k_2=1$ be the principal curvatures of a regular surface $S$ at point $p\in S$ and assume that there is a circle $c$ of radius $1/2$ passing through $p.$ Prove that
>    the geodesic curvature of $c$ satisfies $|k_g|\geqslant 1.$

> 2. Let  $K=0$ be the Gauss curvature of a regular surface $S$ at point $p\in S$ and assume that there is a circle of radius $1$ and a line passing through $p$ that intersect in right angle. Prove that the mean curvature of $S$ at $p$ satisfies $|H|\leqslant 1/2.$

Attempt.

1. Since $k_1=k_2$, point $p$ is umbilic and the normal curvature of $S$ at $p$
   is constant, $k_n=1$. Since $k^2=k_n^2+k_g^2$ and $k=2$ the curvature of $c$, we get $|k_g|=\sqrt{3}$. So $|k_g|\geqslant 1$. I don't seem to find a flow, but i am wondering why $|k_g|=\sqrt{3}$ was not asked in the initial statement.
2. Since $K=0$, one of the principal curvatures is zero, let $k_1=0$, so $|H|\leqslant \frac{|k_1|+|k_2|}{2}=\frac{|k_2|}{2}$, so we need to prove that $|k_2|\leqslant 1$. Of course we need to use the fact that a circle and a line intersect in right angle at $p$ - but how does this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: What is the curvature of a line?

Comment: Zero, of course. But how could this help?(one remark is also that 1,0 are the curvatures if the circle and line, respectively - but how are they connected to principal curvatures?)

Comment: Exactly. What do you know relating curvature and normal curvature?

Comment: Meusnier's theorem is one tool: $k_n=k\cos\phi,$ where $k_n$ is considered at point $p$ at the direction of the tangent vector of the curve. In our case, since both curves belong to a plane, the angle between first normal and the normal of the surface is $\pi/2$, so normal curvature at $p$ considered at the tangent vectors of the line and the circle  (which are perpendicular) are 0 and 1, respectively. (But principal curvature $k_2$ is then at least $1$, being the max value of $k_n$..).

Comment: Your angle thing is wrong, I think. But the line gives $k_n$ equal to what? Thus, the line gives a line of curvature. Now reread hypotheses.